# Reinstall of an In-App purchase application from itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am new to iphone app developing, Now am developing an In-App purchase application.

Developing an application which implements In-App purchage with trial period os one week time, The user install the app & uses it upto the trial period and then he reinstall the from itunes and used one more trial period. What my question is, If he didn,t purchaged app so was not able to reinstall it again. How can I control the user erasing & reinstalling the not purchages the app from itunes.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the user's unique identifier in your server's database, along with the timestamp of the first time the app was opened.  Then, when the user opens the app after the first time, check against the server to make sure their one week hasn't expired.

To get the device's unique identifier, you can use `[[UIDevice sharedDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` which returns a string.  However, this method has been deprecated, so you should look into alternate methods of uniquely identifying the device (for example, by hashing the wifi mac address).

The only limitation of this is that you have to require that the user has internet access in order to be able to launch the app, so if a user disabled Internet access after each reinstall, and kept internet disabled each time he launched the app, there's not much you can do - though it's a tremendous amount of effort to go through to avoid paying a buck for an app.

Example server code:

URL: http://example.com/checkValid.php?udid=A1B2C3D4E5F6

```
$udid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['udid']);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM devices WHERE udid = `$udid`;");
if($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
   $timeElapsed = time() - $r['firstLaunch'];
   if($timeElapsed > 7*24*60*60){  // one week
       echo "expired";
       die();
   }
}else{
   $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO devices (`udid`,`firstLaunch`) VALUES ('$udid','".time()."')");
}
echo "success";
```

Then, in your app, check if the response is `expired`; if it is, tell the user their trial is up.

**A little note about App Store Policies** It is actually *against* Apple's App Store guidelines to create an application which is a "trial" that expires after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Apple has begun rejecting apps that use `[[UIDevice sharedDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`; see the thread started from Karl on the [MKStoreKit blog](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/).

There is code to get the mac address [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015784/how-to-create-uuid-type-1-in-objective-c-ios). You can use it for the basis of creating a UDID. I have read that Apple will also reject an app if it transmits the actual mac address of the device as well, so you will have to convert it into a UDID. That post suggests using the rfc4122 spec.